# Using MediaSource for video with MediaRecord

Tags: javascript, media-source, mediastream, mediarecorder-api

I'm trying to broadcast a video from my webcam in javascript. I'm using `MediaStream` to get the video from my webcam, `MediaRecorder` to record such video in chunks (which would be transmitted to the server), and `MediaSource` to assemble these chunks and play them seamlessly in a video container called `watchVideo` on the source below.

It all works perfectly when i'm capturing only video, i.e. `constraints = { video: true } ;` but if I add audio, the `watchVideo` doesn't display anything, and the console shows me the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
```

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
var mime = 'video/webm; codecs=vp8';


if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
    constraints = { video: true, audio: true };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(handleUserMedia)
    .catch( err => {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err);
    }) 
}

function handleUserMedia(stream) {
    source = new MediaSource();
    watchVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(source);
    source.onsourceopen = () => {
        buffer = source.addSourceBuffer(mime);
    };

    var options = { mimeType: mime }; 
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
}

function handleDataAvailable(evt) {
    var filereader = new FileReader();
    filereader.onload = () => {
        buffer.appendBuffer(filereader.result );
    };
    filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(evt.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the question and it actually helped me more than many answers related to this topic. I don't know if you are still interested in the answer but I have tried

`mime="video/webm; codecs="vp9,opus"`

and it worked fine with audio and video, I hope this answer will help you